# Orthogonal polynomials of the second kind

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, moment-problem

Let $L:  \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive definite linear functional and let that $\{s_n\}$ be a positive semi-definite sequence such that $$L(x^n)= s_n, n\ge 0$$ and $$<p,q> = L(pq).$$ Given a positive definite sequence, we use the Gram-Schimdt orthogonalization method to construct a sequence of orthogonal polynomials $\{p_n\}$ whose leading coefficient is positive due to the  positivity nature of the sequence given. It turns out that this sequence of orthogonal polynomials  $\{p_n\}$ satsifies a three term recurrence relation given below
\begin{equation}
xp_n(x) =b_np_{n+1}(x)+a_np_n(x)+b_{n-1}p_{n-1}(x) , \quad n\ge 0
\end{equation}

We can see the sequence $p_n(x)$ as a solution to the three term recurrence relations stated above. Akhiezer http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf as my reference introduced another solution to this three term recurrence relation by defining another solution by \begin{equation} q_n(x)= \displaystyle L\left(\frac{p_n(x)-p_n(y)}{x-y}\right)
\end{equation} where the  quotient $\frac{p_n(x)-p_n(y)}{x-y}$  is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ and $q_n(x)$ is a polynomial in variable $x$ and its degree is $n-1$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that we have $ \displaystyle xq_n(x) =b_nq_{n+1}(x)+a_nq_n(x)+b_{n-1}q_{n-1}(x), n\ge 1$ with $q_0(x)=0$ and $q_1(x)= \frac{1}{b_0}$

**Question:** Akhiezer claimed that this sequence of polynomials $\{q_n\}$ is orthogonal. I dont understand how this is true. Can anyone please show me what this true?

PS: Recall that $$<p,q> = L(pq)$$ defines an inner product

Comment: The linked pdf isn't readable, unfortunately, not with any tool I've tried. Since the scalar product (or functional) uniquely determines the orthogonal polynomials, Akhiezer can't have meant that the second kind polynomials are orthogonal with respect to _the same_ scalar product. As a well-known example, consider Chebyshev polynomials of first kind, orthogonal with respect to weight function $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$, while Chebyshev polynomials of second kind are orthogonal with respect to weight function $(1-x^2)^{1/2}$. How to prove there is such a scalar product in general, I don't know.

Comment: It would be nice to fix that link. The pdf is not readable. Or at least give a complete reference to the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact what is meant, is that the sequence $(q_n)_{n\ge0}$ is orthogonal with respect to another   positive definite linear functional $\tilde{L}$ (i.e. such that $\tilde{L}(q_n,q_m)=0$ for $ n\ne m$). This, in fact, follows from  a theorem called the **Shohat–Favard theorem** which roughly says that a sequence of polynomials $(q_n)_{n\ge0}$ that satisfy a $3$ terms recurrence relation of the form $$b_{n+1}q_{n+1}(x)= (x-a_n)q_n(x)-b_{n-1}$$ with the first nonzero term being constant, and such that the $a_n$'s are real, and the $b_n$'s are positive, must be orthogonal for some positive linear function $\tilde{L}$.

For more details one may consult [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favard%27s_theorem) and the references therein.

Comment: @Jaynot, you are wellcome, glad that this was helpful.